# Pointwise a.e., strong and weak limit of $f_k$, where $f_k(x) =f\left( kx\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

The 2-Periodic function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows: 
$f(x) =\frac{3}{4}$ when $x \in (0,\frac{2}{3} ] $
and
$f(x) =1$ when $x \in ( \frac{2}{3}, 2  ] . $
 define $f_k(x) =f(kx). $
Do the $f_k$'s all belong to $L_2(0,2 ] $
What can be said about the pointwise ae limit, $L_2(0,2 ] $-norm limit and weak limit of the sequence $\lbrace f_k \rbrace$?

I tried to write down an expression for $f_k(x) $.  It appears to be $f_k(x) = f\left(kx- 2 [  \frac{kx}{2} ] \right). $
The sequence is not pointwise convergent, that is clear. But what about almost everywhere and other convergences?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that 
$$\int_0^2\left\lvert f_n(x)\right\rvert^2\mathrm dx= \int_0^2\left\lvert f(nx)\right\rvert^2\mathrm dx=\frac 1n \sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\int_{2l}^{2l+2}\left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert^2\mathrm dt,               $$
then use periodicity.

For the weak convergence, consider $g\in\mathbb L^2$ and compute 
$$\int_0^2f_n(x)g(x)\mathrm dx=\frac 1n\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\int_{2l}^{2l+2}  f(t)g\left(\frac tn\right)     \mathrm dt .$$